# How do I configure an apache server to serve static content and route all other traffic to second host?

Tags: apache, webserver

I have Apache (2.4) running locally serving port 80 and would like it to directly serve some static content (css/js/etc). I have a weblogic server running on port 8007 that will serve up all the dynamic web pages. I would like some of the static content to be served from the Apache server directly and all other URLs to be routed to the weblogic server. The static content and dynamic content all need to have the same context root (/myRoot). I am trying to use mod_proxy. Here is the current relevant config in httpd.conf which I have tried (assume localhost.mydomain.com maps to 127.0.0.1):

```
ServerName localhost.mydomain.com:80
...
ProxyRequests On
ProxyVia On
...
ProxyPass "/myRoot" "http://localhost.mydomain.com:8007/myRoot"
ProxyPassReverse "/myRoot" "http://localhost.mydomain.com:8007/myRoot"
```

I need the static content URL to be like this and served from Apache directly:
http://localhost.mydomain.com/myRoot/static

The above configuration allows me to connect to the weblogic server running on port 8007 correctly. However Im struggling to get the static content served from the Apache web server. I can get content from htdocs from the apache server but if I put a directory like /htdocs/myRoot/static the static content is still going to the weblogic server.

Answer (score 0):

I found this works. anything with /myRoot goes to the app server unless it also starts with /myRoot/enterprise/js/dojo which are all going to the htdocs directory. In htdocs I placed a folder /apache/htdocs/myRoot/enterprise/js/dojo.

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/myRoot/(enterprise)/(js)/(dojo).* !
ProxyPass "/myRoot" "http://localhost.mydomain.com:8007/myRoot"
ProxyPassReverse "/myRoot" "http://localhost.ntrs.com:8007/myRoot"
```

Unfortunately I also found I probably need to move to using OHS rather than apache to make the webserver work with weblogic correctly so probably will have other issues setting that up =(.

Edit: 
OHS setup was easier than I though. Had to track down some issues with server startup but then I just added this to mod_wl_ohs.conf and added dojo in the htdocs directory directly. below regex will match /myRoot unless it is followed by enterprise/js/dojo. regex are confusing in OHS/Apache - the / doesnt need to be escaped for some reason so took some playing around to get the regex right.

```
<IfModule weblogic_module>
    <LocationMatch "^/myRoot/((?!enterprise/js/dojo).)*$">
      WLSRequest On
      WebLogicHost localhost.mydomain.com
      WebLogicPort 8007
    </LocationMatch>      
</IfModule>
```